# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error' what(): Parenthesis is not closed

Tags: c++, regex

I would to match the string from the first g to the first parentheses in my code. I don't know why this isn't doing this, since I haved used the escape character. 
For example on this string:

hello test g55_2( cnn

I intend to match g55_2
  //g++  5.4.0

```
#include <iostream>
#include<regex>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("g.*\(");
    std::regex re(s);
}
```

I tried my regex here https://regex101.com/ and it worked, but my c++ won't compile due to the error in the title.

Comment: You need to use a raw string literal or escape the backslash.

Comment: `but my c++ won't compile due to the error` I'm pretty sure your c++ compiled. That is a runtime error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You escaped the parenthesis in C++. Regex requires a \ character (which needs to be escaped in C++) and a ( character:

```
std::string s("g.*\\(");
```

Alternatively, use a raw string literal to avoid the need to worry about C++ escaping getting in your way:

```
std::string s(R"(g.*\()");
```

The literal text inside of `R"(...)"` is taken as the string.

Also note that `*` is greedy, but you want it not to be greedy so it stops at the first parenthesis and not the last one. You can add a `?` in to make it non-greedy:

```
std::string s(R"(g.*?\()");
```